# No muestra las etiquetas de primefaces cuando ingreso por plantillas facelets

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="./../WEB-INF/templates/plantilla.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <center>
                <h:form>
                    <h2>Registrar usuario</h2>
                    <p:messages id="mensaje" autoUpdate="false" severity="info , fatal"/>
                    <p:fieldset legend="Datos personales">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="3" id="pjdatos">
                            <p:outputLabel for="txtRut" value="Rut"/>
                            <p:inputText id="txtRut" value="#{usuarioBean.persona.rut}" required="true" requiredMessage="Rut requerido"/>
                            <p:message for="txtRut"/>

                            <p:outputLabel for="txtNombres" value="Nombres"/>       
                            <p:inputText id="txtNombres" value="#{usuarioBean.persona.nombres}" required="true" requiredMessage="Nombres requeridos"/>
                            <p:message for="txtNombres"/>

                            <p:outputLabel for="rbdSexo" value="Sexo"/>
                            <p:selectOneRadio id="rbdSexo" value="#{usuarioBean.persona.sexo}" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor seleccione un sexo">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="Masculino"/>
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="F" itemLabel="Femenino"/>
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                            <p:message for="rbdSexo"/>

                            <p:outputLabel for="fNaci" value="Fec. Nacimiento"/>
                            <p:calendar id="fNaci" requiredMessage="Fecha de nacimiento requerida"  value="#{usuarioBean.persona.fechaNacimineto}" locale="es" required="true"/>
                            <p:message for="fNaci"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:fieldset>

                    <p:fieldset legend="Datos de Cuenta">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="3" id="pjCuenta">
                            <p:outputLabel for="txtUsuario" value="Usuario"/>
                            <p:inputText id="txtUsuario" value="#{usuarioBean.usuarios.usuario}" required="true" requiredMessage="Usuario Requerido"/>
                            <p:message for="txtUsuario"/>

                            <p:outputLabel for="clave1" value="Password"/>
                            <p:password id="clave1" value="#{usuarioBean.usuarios.clave}" required="true" requiredMessage="Password requerido" match="clave2" feedback="true" promptLabel="Ingrese un password" validatorMessage="Las password no coinciden" weakLabel="Debil" strongLabel="Fuerte" goodLabel="Bueno"/>
                            <p:message for="clave1"/>  

                            <p:outputLabel for="clave2" value="Confirmar Password"/>
                            <p:password id="clave2" required="true" requiredMessage="Campo requerido"/>
                            <p:message for="clave2"/>              
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" value="Registrar" update="pjdatos, pjCuenta , mensaje" actionListener="#{usuarioBean.registrar()}"/>
                    </p:fieldset>
                </h:form>
                <h:outputScript  library="js" name="spanishLocal.js"/>
            </center>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

solo me muestra el h2 "Registrar usuario"

Comment: Por favor , ¿ podrias explicar un poco más el problema ?

Comment: y crees que solo con el código y sin los imports vamos a poder saber que es?? pon los imports